# Auth.currentUser alternative firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I use firebase's

```
auth.currentUser
```

for my website, it gets the latest user that logged in, even if multiple users are logged in at the same time. How do I get the info of each user that is logged into their own computer?
I am trying to get each user's unique info when they load into a page, but auth.currentUser has only one user logged in at a time?

Here is how I log users in

```js
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      res.redirect(state)
      console.log(`logged in`)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      return res.render('login', { error: errorMessage, state: '/' })

    });
```

Comment: There cannot be _multiple_ users logged in at the same time if you have only 1 Firebase auth instance. When you login, the current users is logged out. Are you using multiple Firebase instances/projects and still facing this issue? Then please share your code on how you initialize Firebase.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/P94vWzFP this is how I initialize firebase. I assumed that auth.currentUser would get the current user logged into each browser, so that I could fetch each user's data separately

Comment: @FattyDev1 Can  you edit your question to paste the code that you're using for signing users in?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Just did that

Answer (score 2):

`auth.currentUser` is what you seek. Ideally there should not be multiple logged in at the same time in the same browser. `auth.currentUser` will give you different information depening on who is logged in.

If user**A** logs in, `auth.currentUser` will contain information about user**A**.

If user**B** logs in, `auth.currentUser` will contain information about user**B**

and so on...

auth.currentUser is just a local variable in each user's session

Comment: _"There cannot be multiple logged in at the same time in the same browser."_ This is possible when using multiple Firebase projects (or instances temporarily) like `auth1.currentUser` and `auth2.currentUser` but of course is not an ideal way.

Comment: Fair enough! I'll change to *should not* :D

Comment: There is a problem with auth.currentUser. For example, if I log in from **my** browser, another user on another browser is automatically logged in to the account that I just logged into. If they log out of that and log into their account, I will be logged into their account when I log in on my browser.